# To calculate correleation between two large vectors

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

I have some graph with $500$ k nodes. after applying different hierarchical clustering algorithms I want to calculate the cophenetic correlation coefficient.
However, since the pairwise distance vectors length is roughly $n^2$, straight forward correlation calculation is not feasible.

How can I split the calcualtion? Or is there any different approach in order to calculate the cophenetic correlation coefficient?